# Using different layouts in an ASP.NET MVC3 project (Razor)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My ASP.NET MVC3 project consists on the one hand of the Website itself and on the other hand of something like an "Admin control panel". This means I have to use 2 completely different master layouts.

there are several ways to achieve this:

- on top of each admin view, I could add @{ Layout = "~/.../_AdminLayout.cshtml"; }
- I could also use the overloaded View-method in admin controllers, e.g. return View("Index", "_AdminLayout", viewModel);

But both approaches are a little bit in contrast with the DRY principle.

What is the most common approach?
Is there perhaps a way to put some logic in the **_ViewStart** file that can automatically decide whether to use the admin or the normal page layout, if yes, how?

In the case it is helpful, my routings for both sections are different.

```
Normal page: {controller}/{action}/{id}
Admin page: admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about creating an Admin area and setting your admin master layout in the _ViewStart file for the area?

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly hat I thought of, but I need a little bit of help with the decision logic. How can I decide whether to load the normal layout or the admin layout in _ViewStart? See also my edit above. edit: ahh, now i get it. Do you mean a **routing area** by saying "create an admin area"?

Comment: Thank you, i knew that something like this exists but it didn't come to my mind when I need it.